# How to sort two fields in Pandas?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have the following datatype:

```
id=["SA3342","ASD345","SFZX34","ASDFS5","SDFDS4","SFDDSF1"]
arrival_time = ["0"," 2016-05-19 13:50:00","2016-05-19 21:25:00","0","2016-05-24 18:30:00","2016-05-26 12:15:00"]
departure_time = ["2016-05-19 08:25:00","2016-05-19 16:00:00","2016-05-20 07:45:00","2016-05-24 12:50:00","2016-05-25 23:00:00","2016-05-26 19:45:00"]
```

To obtain the following data:

```
id              arrival_time                departure_time
SA3342                 0                  2016-05-19 08:25:00
ASD345          2016-05-19 13:50:00       2016-05-19 16:00:00
SFZX34          2016-05-19 21:25:00       2016-05-20 07:45:00
ASDFS5                    0               2016-05-24 12:50:00
SDFDS4          2016-05-24 18:30:00       2016-05-25 23:00:00
SFDDSF1          2016-05-26 12:15:00       2016-05-26 19:45:00
```

How to sort the datatype based on both "id" and departure time ?

I tried the following code and it didnt work:

```
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'departure_time'], inplace=True, by='date')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: sort_values() got multiple values for keyword argument 'by'
```

Comment: Not so familiar with how to achieve this, but when sorting by more than one value always make sure you are using a stable sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need remove assign if parameter `inplace=True` and also remove second `by` in [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df.sort_values(by=['id', 'departure_time'], inplace=True)    
print (df)
        id          arrival_time       departure_time
1   ASD345   2016-05-19 13:50:00  2016-05-19 16:00:00
3   ASDFS5                     0  2016-05-24 12:50:00
0   SA3342                     0  2016-05-19 08:25:00
4   SDFDS4   2016-05-24 18:30:00  2016-05-25 23:00:00
5  SFDDSF1   2016-05-26 12:15:00  2016-05-26 19:45:00
2   SFZX34   2016-05-19 21:25:00  2016-05-20 07:45:00
```

Or remove `inplace=True` and second `by`:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'departure_time'])    
print (df)
        id          arrival_time       departure_time
1   ASD345   2016-05-19 13:50:00  2016-05-19 16:00:00
3   ASDFS5                     0  2016-05-24 12:50:00
0   SA3342                     0  2016-05-19 08:25:00
4   SDFDS4   2016-05-24 18:30:00  2016-05-25 23:00:00
5  SFDDSF1   2016-05-26 12:15:00  2016-05-26 19:45:00
2   SFZX34   2016-05-19 21:25:00  2016-05-20 07:45:00
```